# Paypal response total amount showing wrongly

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated the PayPal invoice into my website. While I have created the invoice one item with total 3877 but paypal response json showing wronly.

We have pasted the few parts of the code this for creating the invoice.

**PHP CODE**

```
function doCreateAndSendInvoice($aryData, $aryItems)
        {
            $this->end_url = $this->getEndPoint("createAndSendInvoice");
            $strCreateAndSendInvoice = $this->prepareCreateInvoice($aryData, $aryItems);
            $response = $this->curlRequest($strCreateAndSendInvoice);
            $aryRresponse = explode("&", $response);
            $response = $this->parseCurlResponse($aryRresponse);
            return $response;
        }
                $aryData['language'] = "en_US";
                $aryData['merchantEmail'] = 'xxx@mail.com';//$business;
                $aryData['payerEmail'] = $get_user->email;
                $aryData['currencyCode'] = "USD";
                $aryData['orderId'] = 123;//strtotime('now');
                $aryData['invoiceDate'] = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',strtotime($this->input->post('invoice_date')));
                $aryData['dueDate'] =date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',strtotime($this->input->post('due_date')));
                $aryData['paymentTerms'] = "Net45"; 
                $aryData['merchantFirstName'] = "Pheonix ";
                $aryData['merchantLastName'] = "Solutions";
                $aryData['merchantBusinessName'] = "Pheonix Solutions";
                 $aryData['merchantWebsite'] = "https://www.website.com";
                $aryData['merchantCustomValue'] = "xxxxx";
                $aryData['merchantLine1'] = "xxxx";
                $aryData['merchantLine2'] = "xxxx";
                $aryData['merchantCity'] = "xxx";
                $aryData['merchantState'] = "xxxx";
                $aryData['merchantPostalCode'] = "xxx";
                $aryData['merchantCountryCode'] = "xx";

                $aryData['billingFirstName'] = "Billing First Name";
                 $aryData['billingLine1'] = 'xxxx';
                // $aryData['billingLine2'] = "Billing Line 2";
                $aryData['billingCity'] = 'xxxx';
                $aryData['billingState'] = 'xxxx';
                $aryData['billingPostalCode'] = 'xxxx';

                $aryData['billingCountryCode'] = 'xxxx';
                # code...
                $aryItems[0]['name'] = 'title';
                $aryItems[0]['quantity'] = 1;
                $aryItems[0]['unitprice'] = 3877;

                 $res = $this->doCreateAndSendInvoice($aryData, $aryItems);
                    print_r($res);
```

**OUTPUT:**
The output of the above code.

```
 Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2018-03-11T00:01:02.720-08:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Success
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => xxxxxx
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 31634456
    [invoiceID] => xxxxx-xxxxxx
    [invoiceNumber] => QUT-20180311-6
    [invoiceURL] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_inv-details&id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
    [payerViewURL] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi_bin/webscr?cmd=_pay-inv&viewtype=altview&id=xxx-xxxx-xxxxx
    [totalAmount] => 387700
)
```

Comment: You need to show us _all_ relevant code, not just the answer from PayPal (we have no idea of knowing how or what you're actually sending). Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am using create and send an invoice function in php

Comment: You still need to show us your code or we won't have a chance at all to know what happens and why. We can't guess. Please read the links I posted and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: We have updated the post could you please check now.